# date format error in to_date

Tags: sql, function, to-date

**I trying to run this query :**

SELECT

```
   to_date(substr( "SCC_STG_DIM_OVERWRITE_FNL"."TERM_END_DT" , 1, 19), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss.aaaaaaaaa') 

                                                        FROM ("EDMWHS"."SERVICE_CONTRACT" "SERVICE_CONTRACT" INNER JOIN "EDMSTG"."STG_SERVICE_CONTR_DELTA" "STG_SERVICE_CONTR_DELTA" ON
                                                        ( "STG_SERVICE_CONTR_DELTA"."CRM_ORDER_OBJECT_GUID"  =  "SERVICE_CONTRACT"."CRM_ORDER_OBJECT_GUID" )) INNER JOIN
                                                        "EDMSTG"."SCC_STG_DIM_OVERWRITE_FNL" "SCC_STG_DIM_OVERWRITE_FNL" ON ( "SCC_STG_DIM_OVERWRITE_FNL"."CRM_ORDER_OBJECT_GUID"  = 
                                                        "SERVICE_CONTRACT"."CRM_ORDER_OBJECT_GUID" )
                                                        WHERE ( "SCC_STG_DIM_OVERWRITE_FNL"."RECORD_STATUS"  = 'A') and ( "SERVICE_CONTRACT"."RECORD_STATUS"  = 'A')
                                                        ORDER BY  "SERVICE_CONTRACT"."CRM_ORDER_OBJECT_GUID"  ASC ,  "SCC_STG_DIM_OVERWRITE_FNL"."CRM_ORDER_ITEM_GUID"  ASC ;
```

**But I am getting the below error :**
`ORA-01821: date format not recognized`
`01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized`

Why am i getting this error, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
select to_timestamp('2016-01-01 14:08:13.123456789', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss.ff9')
from dual;
```

Your code has two errors.  The fractional seconds are represented by `ff`, not `aa`.  And, `to_date()` doesn't support fractional seconds, so you probably intend `to_timestamp()`.